# Check if a value exists in JSON data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, json

I have JSON data in MySQL like this:

```json
[ { "dates": [ "25.01.2021", "25.01.2021" ], "uids": { "1", "2"}, "names": [ "FileEX", "PlayerEZ" ] } ]
```

I want check if, e.g., '1' exists in 'uids'. (If the user id exists in a JSON table). I think I should use a JSON_CONTAINS or JSON_EXTRACT function, but how should I use this for this?

Comment: Your JSON is not valid.

Comment: Specifically, `{ "1", "2"}` is a JSON object, so it should contain `"name": "value"` pairs. But you are using it like an array, which must have `[ ]` brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT JSON_SEARCH(JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.uids'), 'one', '1') IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85bfc2ca2c8cf765f21c13fb4e33e64f)

Answer (score 0):

First of it should have the correct code.
As we can see, you have declared an Array and inside the array, there is a set.
The first key has value as an array
The second key has value as a set and the third key again has value as an array.